# TransactionScope with two datacontexts doesn't roll back

Tags: entity-framework, transactionscope

I am trying to solve situation with rolling back our datacontexts. 
We are using one TransactionScope and inside two data contexts of two different databases.

At the end we want to save changes on both databases so we call .SaveChanges but the problem is that when an error occurs on the other database the changes on the first database are still saved.

What am I doing wrong in there that the first database doesn't roll back?

Thank you,

Jakub

```
     public void DoWork()
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (var rawData = new IntranetRawDataDevEntities())
                {
                    rawData.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

                    using (var dataWareHouse = new IntranetDataWareHouseDevEntities())
                    {
                        dataWareHouse.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

... some operations with the data - no savechanges() is being called.

```
                        // Save changes for all items.
                        if (!errors)
                        {
// First database save.
                            rawData.SaveChanges();

// Fake data to fail the second database save.
                            dataWareHouse.Tasks.Add(new PLKPIDashboards.DataWareHouse.Task()
                                {
                                    Description = string.Empty,
                                    Id = 0,
                                    OperationsQueue = new OperationsQueue(),
                                    Queue_key = 79,
                                    TaskTypeSLAs = new Collection<TaskTypeSLA>(),
                                    Tasktype = null
                                });

// Second database save.
                            dataWareHouse.SaveChanges();

                            scope.Complete();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            scope.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/01/11/savechanges-false.aspx

try to use

```
rawData.SaveChanges(false);

dataWareHouse.SaveChanges(false);

//if everything is ok

scope.Complete();
rawData.AcceptAllChanges();
dataWareHouse.AcceptAllChanges();
```

Comment: Hello, the problem is that SaveChanges(false) is not working here. The SaveChanges() doesn't support that "false" overload. I guess it's given by that entity model context.